# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (sizzle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thank you in advance.

I've checked a few of the "unrecognized expression" errors on stackoverflow. 
All of them suggested error on the side of selector. But from what I get here I understand that the error comes up with the variable "obj" or JSON.stringify. 
I somehow think that this error is sth simple that eludes me and it bugs me even more.

This has bugged me since last wednesday. Help will be greatly appreciated.

I have this part of code:

```
function bake_cookie()
        {
            var array = [];
            ///zbieram wiersze z tabeli
            $("#here tr").each(function(){



                var obj = 
                    {
                        id: $(this).attr('id'),
                        nazwa: $($(this).children('td.findN')).html(),
                        kod: $($(this).children('td.kod')).html(),
                        netto: $($(this).children('td.netto')).html(),
                        vat: $($(this).children('td.vat')).html(),
                        cena: $($(this).children('td.cena')).html(),
                        kategoria: $($(this).children('td.kat')).html(),
                        opcje: $($(this).children('td.opcja')).html(),
                        ocena: $($(this).children('td.ocena')).html()
                    }
                array.push(obj);


            })
            //sa obiekty, prawidlowo sformatowane
            //teraz stringify
            console.log(array);

            var cookie = JSON.stringify(array);
            console.log(cookie);
            $.cookie('table_cookie', cookie, { expires: 0.0035 })

            //var cookie_back = JSON.parse($.cookie('table_cookie'));
            //console.log(cookie_back);
        }
```

And this creates great cookie, no error.

I do this:

```
function add(locator) {

            var array = [];

            var item = ($(locator).closest('tr'));

            console.log(item)

            if($.cookie('shoping_cart')==null)
            {

                console.log($($(item).find('.findN')).html());
                //stworz obiekt z danych
                var obj =
                    {
                    nazwa: $($(item).find('.findN')).html(),
                    netto: $($(item).find('.netto')).html(),
                    vat: $($(item).find('.vat')).html().trim(),
                    brutto: $($(item).find('.cena')).html()
                }
                //push obiekt
                console.log("push" + " " + obj);

                array.push(obj);
                //stringify
                console.log("stringify")
                var str_array = JSON.stringify(array);
                //stworz ciastko
                $('shoping_cart', str_array, { expires: 0.0035 });

            }
            else
            {
                var par_array = JSON.parse($.cookie('shoping_cart'));
                //pobierz ciastko
                array.push(par_array);
                //do array of elements (parse json)
                var obj = {
                    nazwa: $($(item).find('.findN')).html(),
                    netto: $($(item).find('.netto')).html(),
                    vat: $($(item).find('.vat')).html(),
                    brutto: $($(item).find('.cena')).html(),
                    ilosc: 1
                };
                //push nowy element do array
                array.push(obj);
                //stringify i nadpisz ciastko
                var str_array = JSON.stringify(array);
                //stworz ciastko
                $('shoping_cart', str_array, { expires: 0.0035 });
            }

            console.log(array);
        }
```

locator in this function is THIS paremeter from onClick function in the table:

[image]

And get this error:

[image]

Comment: Why all those cloned collections: `$($(...).find(...))` ? Just do `$(item).find('.findN').html()` (for example). And what is this supposed to do: `$('shoping_cart', str_array, { expires: 0.0035 });` ? There's [no constructor which takes three parameters](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

Comment: sounds like you are passing in the wrong thing to the method... It expects a selector and you are giving it some object.

Comment: @Andreas you've actually pointed out 1 error - I wished for $.cookie :) will check it out

Comment: @epascarello guys it actually was the cause of the whole error... I forgot about $.cookie and used $ instead... facepalm